# Code formatting bleeding into tags/user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting

It looks like the code formatting from question [Object.GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139767/object-gethashcode) is bleeding over into tags and the user profile information.  I haven't seen this on any other questions but it appears to be happening in FF 4b11 & IE 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible due to old bugs in the Markdown renderer. We store the rendered HTML at the time of save, so if it was saved a long time ago.. etc.

I just edited, entered a space, and clicked save.