# Tags and user icon are styled as code when the question ends with indented code

Tags: bug, design, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code formatting bleeding into tags/user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80387/code-formatting-bleeding-into-tags-user-profile)

This is a reincarnation of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80387/159624).

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/180894/cannot-play-audio-cds-on-linux-buffer-i-o-error-on-device-sr0), the post ends with four-space indented code, and it bleeds into the tags and the user profile.

[image]

I believe this should be fixed – there are lots of possibilities where questions could end with blocks of code.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I've surely seen posts that end with formatted code on Stack Overflow but not noticed this bug. Wonder why it's just appearing on Super User?

Comment: @Arjan [Copy Question Link Markdown - Making it easier to copy links to questions!](http://stackapps.com/q/2150/7682)

Comment: This *is* long fixed. The answer is the same as in the other post -- just make an edit to force re-rendering of the Markdown (I just did that with your example).

Comment: @balpha Ah. I had only changed the tags, which didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Yep, changing the tags will not cause the post body to be re-rendered.